# How the Inline functions having multiple lines of code are treated as a single line?

Tags: c++, inline-functions

I have an idea on defining inline functions(normal functions) globally 
 using "inline keyword" increases performance if the snippet is small.I have 
 a doubt that :
 "how  the member functions defined inside classes
 also gives the same performance and considered as inline?"

Comment: *"inline functions contain a single line of code"* Where is that from?

Comment: _"Actually inline functions contain a single line of code"_ There's no constraint forcing that. It will be often the case for simple getter/setter functions, but absolutely no requirement.

Comment: "Actually inline functions contain a single line of code" -- where did you read that?

Comment: "Actually inline functions contain a single line of code..." - No. That simply plain *wrong*.

Comment: The term "line" is mostly useless in C++. You can put all of a function with multiple statements into a single line, the semicolons make it sufficiently readable for the compiler (not to a human though).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Actually inline functions contain a single line of code

This statement is wrong. There's no such constraint.

*Inline function* merely means that all the function definition code is placed directly where it is *declared*.

> but member functions defined inside a class contain multiple code instead treated as inline why?

If you're referring to the `inline` keyword there's also no constraint that functions marked with that keyword can only contain a single line of code.

If it's actually inlined by the compiler (i.e. assembly code directly inserted in place, without a function call) is left to its decision, and mostly depends on compiler optimization strategies chosen in the optimization flags.

---

You need to provide the `inline` keyword for non class member functions if they are completely defined in a header file to avoid ODR violation errors.

Here's an example (header file assumed):

```
class foo {
    int x_;

public:
     // Inside the class declaration 'inline' is assumed as default
     int x() const { return x_; }
     int y() const {
         int result = 0;
         // Do some complicated calculation spanning 
         // a load of code lines
         return result;
     }
};

inline int bar() { // inline is required here, otherwise the compiler
                   // will see multiple definitions of that function
                   // in every translation unit (.cpp) that includes
                   // that header file.
    return 42;
}
```

Comment: `inline` has nothing to do with function inlining. It's just a funny way of spelling "this thing is allowed to have more than one definition".

Comment: @molbdnilo Didn't I say that clear enough? I mentioned the ODR violation that will apply otherwise.

Comment: "If it's actually inlined by the compiler" seemed to imply that you believe that they are related, but I probably misunderstood you.

Comment: @molbdnilo I tried to express the opposite. Putting the `inline` keyword or not won't have any influence on how the compiler emits the corresponding machine code (function call or _inlined_). I rarely rely on _"belief"_ regarding any programming language BTW. As working about 30 as a professional software developer, that always tuned out to be a bad idea ;-) ...

Answer (score 2):

Inline doesn't mean its just single line of code . It means the whole code if it is single line or multiple lines gets inserted at the function calling point thereby reducing function call overhead .

Comment: Your 2nd sentence only tells half of what's actually true.

Comment: `inline` has nothing to do with function inlining.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this code, I know it's not C++ but basics are the same.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define inlineMacro(x) ((x) = (x) + 1); ((x) = (x) * 2)

int main()
{
    int i = 5;
    inlineMacro(i);
    printf("%i",i);

return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
12
```

You can put all of your code on single line. So don't be detracted by keyword inline, it's just for compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I have got a clear explanation from all of you guys.

INTUITION in three 4 points:

1.For normal functions(not methods that are declared /defined in classes) inline keyword is used to interpolate the assembly code (by compiler),thereby avoiding repeating function calls.

2.For methods declared inside classes ,the performance would be same if they are declared as normal functions with inline keyword(no class concept) for a small snippet.

3.method declaration(for classes) is implicit inline.

4.functions declaration is (if needed) is explicit inline.